# Using dplyr to subset a data based on common values in one column from two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have never really used dplyr and wondering how I can use it in the following context. So, I have following two data frames:

```
 trainData <- read.csv("train.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 subscriptionData <- read.csv("subscriptions.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> head(trainData)
       account.id total
1 001i000000NuOGY     0
2 001i000000NuS8r     0
3 001i000000NuPGw     0
4 001i000000NuO7a     0
5 001i000000NuQ2f     0
6 001i000000NuOQz     0

> head(subscriptionData)
       account.id    season package no.seats          location           section price.level total multiple.subs
1 001i000000LhyR3 2009-2010 Quartet        2     San Francisco Premium Orchestra           1   1.0            no
2 001i000000NuOeY 2000-2001    Full        2     San Francisco         Orchestra           2   2.0            no
3 001i000000NuNvb 2001-2002    Full        2 Berkeley Saturday     Balcony Front           3   2.0            no
4 001i000000NuOIz 1993-1994 Quartet        1      Contra Costa         Orchestra           2   0.5            no
5 001i000000NuNVE 1998-1999    Full        2   Berkeley Sunday      Balcony Rear           4   2.0            no
```

Now I want to take subset of `subscriptionData` based on the `account.id` of `trainData`. I basically want to take subset of `subscriptionData` with `account.id` that are also present in `trainData`.

I know it's a very basic question but I am totally new dplyr and have no clue.

Comment: `subscriptionData %>% filter(account.id %in% trainData$account.id)` assuming the id's are unique.

Comment: @hmi You could use `inner_join` i.e. `inner_join(subscriptionData, trainData[,'account.id',drop=FALSE], by='account.id')`

Answer (score 4):

You want a semi join:

```
subscriptionData %>% semi_join(trainData, by = "account.id")
```

Comment: @Burimi huh? This does answer the question.

Comment: save a bit of typing that silly pipe symbol: `semi_join(subscriptionData, trainData, by="account.id")` - I mean pipes are lovely when you are chaining a bunch of them but lets not get hooked on pipes.

Comment: @Spacedman yes, it's not necessary here, but it is likely to be used in a sequence of transformations